MODIS PAR data - Light intensity data
I need light intensity data for my analysis. I am using MODIS PAR (MCD18A2 PAR) data to collect light intensity information globally on specific days. However my PAR data values are coming to big (attaching the snap). light intensity data values
We have downloaded the PAR hdf file according to specific lat, long, and sampling dates. Is this the right way to download the data or do I need some conversion factor to get the exact values of light intensity? Or the other best way to get light intensity data.
